# Looping through multiple websites beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data through numerous web pages from a second-hand car website. I tried to loop through each page but Its printing duplicates of the same car. I tried a for loop to loop through each page but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me?

```
import csv ,requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.carsireland.ie/used-cars?page="

for page in range(0, 2):
    req = requests.get(url + str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    rows = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "listing__details listing__details--desktop"})
    listings = soup.find_all('article')

#var = [i['src'] for i in soup.select('article img', '')]
#print(var)

    with open("carsTest.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        fields = ['Name', 'Location', 'Mileage', 'Colour', 'Year', 'Price', 'Main Image', 'Image2', 'Image3']
        writer.writerow(fields)



        for row in rows:
            carname = row.find('h2').text.strip()
            carlocation = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-location"}).text.strip()
            carmileage = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-data-mileage"}).text.strip()
            carcolour = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-color"}).text.strip()
            caryear = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-data-year"}, 'p').text.strip()
            carprice = next(row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-pricing"}).strings).strip()

            for listing in listings:
                large = listing.select_one('.listing__images--main img')['src']
                small_top = listing.select_one('.listing__images--small img')['src']
                small_btm = listing.select_one('.listing__images--small img + img')['src']


                carrow = [carname, carlocation, carmileage, carcolour, caryear, carprice, large, small_top, small_btm]
                writer.writerow(carrow)

                print(carname, carlocation, carmileage, carcolour, caryear,carprice, large, small_top, small_btm)
```

Comment: you are dealing with a website which is protected via `cloudflare` and `HiCAPTCHA`, so i will not be able to help you bypassing `CAPTCHA` AS IT'S IMPLEMENTED TO PREVENT SUCH CASE.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass that

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is inside inner for loop

try this:

```
with open("carsTest.csv", "a", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    fields = ['Name', 'Location', 'Mileage', 'Colour', 'Year', 'Price', 'Main Image', 'Image2', 'Image3']
    writer.writerow(fields)



    for row in rows:
        carname = row.find('h2').text.strip()
        carlocation = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-location"}).text.strip()
        carmileage = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-data-mileage"}).text.strip()
        carcolour = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-color"}).text.strip()
        caryear = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-data-year"}, 'p').text.strip()
        carprice = next(row.find('div', {"class": "listing__details-pricing"}).strings).strip()

        for listing in listings:
            large = listing.select_one('.listing__images--main img')['src']
            small_top = listing.select_one('.listing__images--small img')['src']
            small_btm = listing.select_one('.listing__images--small img + img')['src']


            carrow = [carname, carlocation, carmileage, carcolour, caryear, carprice, large, small_top, small_btm]
        writer.writerow(carrow)

        print(carname)
        print("---------")
```

I would also suggest to do the same with `writer.writerow(carrow)` to avoid writing in csv multiple times

I think the problem is with 'w' in  `with open("carsTest.csv", "w", newline="") as file:` line replace it with 'a' which will append data because you are always opening the file and writing above it

Comment: It fixed it do you have an idea why it's not looping through the each webpage

Comment: Great I coud have but i dont have access to the website [carsireland.ie](https://www.carsireland.ie/used-cars) don't know why.

Comment: @BenjaminWaife I have edited the answer read last paragraph.